# Nullable value types & type safety with 'if not null checking' in c#. Does C# have 'Type promotion'?

Tags: c#

In other languages (eg Dart), if you do an `if (x != null)` check then the x will be promoted to a non nullable type.  Does c# have type promotion?  What are the limitations in C#? eg `if (x is Y)` or in switch commands and other scenarios?

I have noticed nullable types are not promoted to non nullable types in C#.  Is there any feature that can be turned on or this is this a limitation in the language?

```
public enum eColours { blue }

public class ColourClass {
  public eColours? call(string colour) {
    if (colour == "blue")
      return eColours.blue;

    return null;
  }

  public string describeColour(eColours colour) => colour.ToString();
}

var obj = new ColourClass();
var result = obj.call("blue");

if (result is not null) {
  var description1 = obj.describeColour(result); //error here
}
```

**Edit**

The particular solution I'm trying to solve has an `&&` clause in the `if` expression? (Where colour & pet are both enums?)

`if (colour != null && pet != null pet)`

Comment: As an aside, pattern matching is your friend here in more ways than one -- `call` could be written as `public eColours? call(string colour) => colour switch { "blue" => eColours.blue, _ => null }`.

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't know what `eColours` is. Is that a value type or a reference type? A *complete* example would be much easier to reason about - ideally following C# naming conventions too.

Comment: Instead of `var description1 = obj.describeColour(result);` just put `var description1 = obj.describeColour(result.Value);`

Comment: In fact I'd use `result.HasValue` rather than `result is not null`: `if (result.HasValue) { var description1 = obj.describeColour(result.Value); }` (which means the question doesn't arise, of course)

Comment: @JonSkeet the e is supposed to signify an enum so eColours is a value type

Comment: Rather than assume everyone else knows the non-standard conventions you use, it would be better to provide a [mcve] that follows the standard conventions. It would also make it easy for anyone to test a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the variables being tested aren't promoted themselves, you can expand your use of the `is` operator slightly to achieve what you're after:

```
if (result is eColours nonNullResult) {
  var description1 = obj.describeColour(nonNullResult);
}
```

This syntax combines both the type check and a cast to another variable if the type check is successful; the type of `nonNullResult` is specifically `eColours`, not `eColours?`, and you no longer get the conversion error.

In later versions of the language, you can also specifically check for not-null with this format:

```
if (result is { } nonNullResult)
```

Comment: that's great, thanks for your input. I prefer the Dart way as less code & fewer variables but this works well and solves my problem.

Comment: actually just looked at my original code and this doesn't solve it unfortunately (I had simplified my code too much for the example!)\. My code actually has an `and` clause.  `if (colour != null && pet != null pet)` what would be the solution here?  A nested `if` clause?

Comment: @atreeon: It could easily be `if (colour is Colour nonNullColour && pet is Pet nonNullPet)`

Comment: oh yes, thanks @JonSkeet, I had made a mistake and it does work!